# Why does the Process.Exited event fire two times?

Tags: c#, events, process

I am writing an application in C# to download images using the `Process` class and `wget.exe`.

I want to handle the `Process.Exited` event without calling `WaitForExit` because calling `WaitForExit` hangs my UI. To work around this, I have tried many techniques like calling both `Process.Start()` and `Process.WaitForExit()` on another thread, using a `BackgroundWorker` etc.  Still, my UI hangs at some level. So now I want simply handle the `Process.Exited` event without `WaitForExit`.

My code is:

```
bool processComplete = false;
Process process = new Process();

private void Start()
{
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "path of wget";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "arguments for downloading images";
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.Exited += new EventHandler(Process_Complete);
    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hide;            
    process.Start();
}

private void Process_Complete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    processComplete = true;
}
```

After starting the process, the `Process.Exited` event fires two times. First, while process is going on in between if some times downloading become slow(if images are more than 1000 etc ow at the starting only it fires `process.exited event`) and then after all images are downloaded,

I would expect the `Process.Exited` event to fire once.  Why is it firing twice?

Comment: Are you sure that Start function is not executed twice? Is there any other place where Process_Complete is subscribed?

Comment: Can you please rewrite that next-to-last paragraph, more carefully this time? It's really hard to understand what you're trying to say, other than that the event is raised twice (i.e. everything after the first sentence is garbled).

Comment: @AlexFarber: it's a good guess, except that I _think_ the OP is saying in his next-to-last paragraph that the event is being raised first while the process is still actually running.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue.
I guess it's somehow related to accessing process members from different threads (in my case at least), 'cause from the log it's clear that handler is called from different threads.
Anyway, my solution was to unsubscribe from event in event handler:

```
bool processComplete = false;
Process process = new Process();

private void Start()
{
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "path of wget";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "arguments for downloading images";
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.Exited += Process_Complete;
    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hide;            
    process.Start();
}

private void Process_Complete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    process.Exited -= Process_Complete;
    processComplete = true;
}
```

I think alternative solution might be to synchronize access to process instance (using lock for example).